# Missing FileIOPermission class .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, .net

According to MSDN, System.Security.Permissions should contain a FileIOPermission class. See picture one. But in my object brower this class is missing. See picture two. I am using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate and .NET 4.5. Is there a way for using the FileIOPermission class?

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Use Resharper and enter the class name in the Ctrl-T dialog.

Comment: Just type the name in the Search box.

Comment: As for your answer/edit, that class isn't in .NET 4.5 for Store Apps. Please explain why you think you need this exception in a Store App.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong assembly. The [`FileIOPermission`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.fileiopermission%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class resides in `mscorlib`:

mscorlib > System.Security.Permissions > FileIOPermission.

Comment: I tried the right assembly. I got a notification that System.Security.Permissions was added to my references. But strangely it was not added to my references.

Comment: I added some pictures with a clearer explanation of my problem.

Comment: In my datamodel I have a json file representing the data shown in my split view. I want to update this data programmatically  but I get a UnauthorizedAccessException. So I thought using FileIOPermissions for updating the json file.

Answer (score 1):

You are in the wrong assembly. you can use it by `using System.Security.Permissions;` and `FileIOPermission f = new FileIOPermission(foo);`